# PHP: Taking Array (CSV) And Intelligently Returning Information

Tags: php, arrays, csv, information-retrieval

Hey Everyone. I'm a first time poster, but I've browsed this site a number of times. I have a coding issue that I'm not sure exactly how to solve. First I'll explain what I need to do, and what information I have, and I hope somebody can give me a nudge in the right direction.

What I have is a spreadsheet (CSV) that has the following info: Zone Name, Zip Code, City Name. One zone should have many cities that fall under it, and every city most likely has many zip codes that fall under it. For example:

> Zone H, 92603, Irvine
>
> Zone H, 92604, Irvine
>
> Zone J, 92625, Corona
>
> etc.

Okay, now that that's out of the way, here's what I need to do with this info. I need to be able to input a city name and have it return to me all zip codes that fall under that city, as well as the zone that the city lies in. For example, if I input Chatsworth, it should give me (Zone X) and (12345, 12346, 12347) as the zip codes (just an example).

I'm not sure the best way to go about this. I could create a MySQL database and work from there, or just work from .csv files, or hardcode it into the PHP file. I don't know how to search for a value in an array column, and then return the other columns accordingly (especially with multiple zip codes per city).

If anybody can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. Also, feel free to let me know if you need more information from me. Thanks in advance to everyone reading.

Comment: fixed my code below, see comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Zone H, 92603, Irvine
>
> Zone H, 92604, Irvine
>
> Zone J, 92625, Corona
>
> etc.

you can take the file and get all its contents. then split it up by new line:

```
$searchCity = 'Searched'; //or whatever city you are looking for
$file = file_get_contents('file.csv');
$results = array();
$lines = explode("\n",$file); 
//use any line delim as the 1st param,
//im deciding on \n but idk how your file is encoded

foreach($lines as $line){
    //split the line
    $col = explode(",",$line);
    //and you know city is the 3rd element
    if(trim($col[2]) == $searchCity){
         $results[] = $col;
    }
}
```

and at the end u have an array of the results like this:

```
$results = array(
   array('Zone B', '12345', 'Searched'),
   array('Zone Z', '35145', 'Searched'),
   array('Zone Q', '12365', 'Searched'),
)
```

Comment: How exactly does this answer OP's question?

Comment: @Brian so explode by that ^_^

Comment: @Neal I think you're missing the point. You've assumed by your solution that OP knows what the newline encoding will be. What if that's not the case?

Comment: @Brian -- i added a comment to note that fact

Comment: @Wiseguy, its not needed, `file_get_contents` works just as well for what he needs

Comment: Sure, but if you're going to do it that way and you have PHP 5.3, you could use `str_getcsv()` http://php.net/str_getcsv

Comment: Not that any of these ways is wrong or right; just giving different options. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I was misleading with my original question. The CSV file is already split up into columns. I don't need help on dividing each line into separate variables. I need to know how I can input a City name, and have it search the entire csv file for that city name, then output the zip codes and zone name that correspond to it.

Comment: Okay I'm trying it out. I'm guessing instead of file_get_content you meant file_get_contents? I'll let you know if this solution works for me in a few minutes.

Comment: @Kevin, yes. fixed that, sorry typo

Comment: I tried this out, and used print_r to try and display the array. What outputted was: Array ( ). What could be the problem? It seems like maybe the line delim is wrong.. but what else could it be besides \n? I am pretty certain that's what it is. It's just a linebreak. Any advice?

Comment: @Kevin , i fixed my code above, it could have to do with using single vc double quotes, i changed that explode to double quotes, try it now :-)

Comment: Yeah it works, only thing is each listing in the .csv file is surrounded with double quotes. So I used "IRVINE" as the search term and it worked. How can we eliminate the double quotes?

Comment: well either fix your csv or search inside the `$col[2]` and remove the double quotes

Comment: yeah I just fixed the csv, much easier. Thanks, I think this may be a good starting point for me.. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Kevin - no problem. on stackoverflow is is common courtesy to select an answer as accepted, that answered your Q, that way on future questions people would want to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pursue the CSV approach, then the first step is reading the file into a 2D array:

```
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("file.csv"));
```

Now this is an indexed array, where you need to know which column is which. But if you know the city is always in `[2]` then searching for the other information becomes simple:

```
foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
    if ($row[2] == "Chatsworth") {
        $zone = $row[0];
        $zip = $row[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Ideally you would put this into a function, so you can call it multiple times. It would be easiest if you make it configurable which column to search, and just have it return the complete found row.

---

Okay so if you don't know where the $city name is in, then I would propose following utility function:

```
function search_csv($city) {
    global $csv;   // pre-parsed array (can be parameter though)

    foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
        if (in_array($city, $row)) {
            $result_rows[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $result_rows;
}

function search_zip($city) {
    $rows = search_csv($city);
    foreach ($rows as $i=>$row) { 
        $rows[$i] = end(array_filter($row, "is_numeric"));
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

The first one returns a list of $rows which match. I'll leave it up to you how to figure out which column contains which. Only for the zip code it's kind of possible to return the results deterministically.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a step in the right direction.. But let's say I don't know which row the city is in (which happens to be the case). Would I just replace the numbers in the []'s with $i, so it searches the current line? I don't know where the city is so I must search for it. And the information I need will be in the same row as the city. However, some rows have the same city name, with a different zip code. So I need to grab the different zip codes which are in different rows, and apply them to that cityname. Maybe I could just do something like $zip .= $row[] . ", ";?

Comment: @Kevin: The other way round. To collect an array of zip codes you would use `$zip[] = $row[1];`. But if you don't know which column the city name is in, then you probably won't know in advance which one holds the numeric zip code, right? The searching issue can be solved, but the finding the right result is a showstopper.

Comment: Can't you just do `foreach ($row as $key => $col) {if ($col == "Chatsworth") { /* $key is the index where the city is. */ }}`?

Comment: @Bruno: True. Come to think of it `$key = array_search("Chatsworth", $row);` might also work.

Comment: I'm going to try this out.. thank you so much for your help, I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: @Kevin: No worries. Try the first answer part in any case. It parses the CSV file correctly without having to rework any quotes. You can still use whatever other approaches the answer or your discussion with Neal led to. Your case sounds a bit more complicated, so you just might have to try everything through.. ;}