# Echo selective data (rows) from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, selection

I have an array coming from a .csv file. These are coming from a real estate program. In the second column I have the words For Sale and in the third column the words For Rent that are indicated only on the rows that are concerned. Otherwise the cell is empty. I want to display a list rows only For Sale for example. Of course then if the user clicks on a link in one of the rows, the appropriate page will be displayed.
I can't seem to target the text in the column, and I can't permit that the words For Sale be used throughout the entire array because they could appear in another column (description for example).
I have tried this, but to no avail.

```
/* The array is $arrCSV */
foreach($arrCSV as $book) {
    if($book[1] === For Sale) {
      echo '<div>';
    }
    echo '<div>';
    echo $book[0]. '<br>';
    echo $book[1]. '<br>';
    echo $book[2]. '<br>';
    echo $book[3]. '<br>';
    echo $book[6]. '<br><br><br>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I also tried this:

```
foreach($arrCSV as $key => $book) {
    if($book['1'] == 'For Sale') {
      echo '<div>';
    }
    echo '<div>';
    echo $book[0]. '<br>';
    echo $book[1]. '<br>';
    echo $book[2]. '<br>';
    echo $book[3]. '<br>';
    echo $book[6]. '<br><br><br>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
foreach($arrCSV as $key => $book) {
    if($book['1'] == 'For Sale') {
        echo '<div></div>';
    }else{
        echo '<div>';
        echo $book[0]. '<br>';
        echo $book[1]. '<br>';
        echo $book[2]. '<br>';
        echo $book[3]. '<br>';
        echo $book[6]. '<br><br><br>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really need an else condition. I just want to selectively show certain rows (or lines). After having posted I have found a solution

Comment: You should post your solution so that [anybody searching](http://xkcd.com/979/) will be able to see it

Comment: @ianbarker: I tried, but because I have a rank less than 100 I must wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:
[PHP: Taking Array (CSV) And Intelligently Returning Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463168/php-taking-array-csv-and-intelligently-returning-information)

```
$searchCity = 'For Sale'; //or whatever you are looking for
$file = file_get_contents('annonces.csv');
$results = array();
$lines = explode("\n",$file); 
//use any line delim as the 1st param,
//im deciding on \n but idk how your file is encoded

foreach($lines as $line){
//split the line
$col = explode(";",$line);
//and you know city is the 3rd element
if(trim($col[1]) == $searchCity){
     $results[] = $col;
}
}
```

And then:

```
foreach($results as $Rockband)
{
echo "<tr>";
foreach($Rockband as $item)
{
echo "<td>$item</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
```

As you can see I'm learning. It turns out that by formulating a question, a series of similar posts are displayed, which is much quicker and easier than using google. Thanks.